# How to pass an env variable in CAPL trough a function?

Tags: capl

I would like to set environment variables with a function. Is it even possible?

```
void SetEnvVariable(byte env_flag, byte ret_val)
{
    putValue(env_flag, ret_val);
}
```

I get this error:

```
Error     1030 at (83,14): Environment variable expected. Database missing? test.cin
```

Answer (score 0):

the CAPL function putValue require Environment variable name (on first parameter). 
you cannot pass char name/value on first parameter by user defined function to this putValue. 
what you can do is an workaround with hard bind the envar to if/switch case for example:

```
void SetEnvVariable(byte env_flag, byte ret_val)
{
    if(env_flag==1)
    {
      putValue(Switch_K1, ret_val);
    }
    if(env_flag==2)
    {
      putValue(Switch_K2, ret_val);
    }
}
```

where environment variable name Switch_K1 and Switch_K2 must be exist.

Note: The creation of environment variables is no longer supported. Instead, use system variables directly in CANoe. Currently CANoe still supports the use of environment variables. This support will not be available in future versions.